# Why enumeration typenames are preceded with the number of characters in the enumeration name?

Tags: c++, enums

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

enum class Colors
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
};

int main ()
{
    std::cout << typeid(Colors::Red).name();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is `6Colors`. That's true even if the enumeration is "not scoped" (enum without the `class` keyword). When another enumeration is defined, say `Animals`, its type name becomes `7Animals`. Although this may hardly be something to consider in the future, I am interested to know why the compiler does that.

Comment: "The output of the above program is `6Colors`" --- it depends on the implementation (compiler version, platform)

Comment: This is called "name mangling", and every compiler [has its own way of doing it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions).

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 outputs "enum Colors" and "enum Animals". *shrug* Voodoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing a mangled name - which is designed to encode namespace scope and type information as well as the name.

Boost has a handy cross-platform way of demangling these names which you may find interesting to play with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

enum class Colors
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
};

int main ()
{
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(Colors::Red).name());

    return 0;
}
```